# How to create a Ransack search on an array field in Rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have a developers table with a schedule_interview_date field, which is an array of dates. I want to create a Ransack search on this field for last position value of  array of schedule_interview_date.

schedule_interview_date data contain in array like the below :-

[[Mon, 21 Jan 1980 00:00:00.000000000 IST +05:30, Sat, 02 Feb 1980 04:03:00.000000000 IST +05:30]]

Here's my controller method:

```
def index
    session[:current_page] ="all_request"
    pagination_per_page_value
    @q = ClientRequest.with_resource_info_and_developer.page(params[:page]).per(@per_page).ransack(params[:q])
    if(params[:q] && @filter_per_page_value = params[:q][:per_page_eq]) != nil
      @per_page = @filter_per_page_value
      @q = ClientRequest.with_resource_info_and_developer.page(params[:page]).per(@per_page).ransack(params[:q]) 
    end
    kanban_view_details
  end
```

And here's my ClientRequest model:

```
class ClientRequest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :developers, through: :resource_infos
end
```

and below is my ransack search field in view file

```
  <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>Interview Date</label>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <%= f.date_field :developers_schedule_interview_date_gteq, class:"fa fa-calendar form-control", id: "fromdate-form" %>
              <%= image_tag("datepickerArrow.svg", alt: "image is not loaded", class:"date-img") %>
              <%= f.date_field :developers_schedule_interview_date_lteq, class:"fa fa-calendar form-control", id: "todate-form" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I try to search on this field, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: I would really recommend that you setup a separate table and an association instead of using an array column which is an anti-pattern and which will making querying a pain in the backside. https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/#multiple-values-per-column